# Downloading song preview m4a file from iTunes and merging it into recorded video

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes, avplayer, m4a

I have used [iTunes api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to search songs in iTunes store and after that user will select a song preview to merge it into previously recorded video.

e.g. [here](http://a1930.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/022/Music/v4/a4/ac/63/a4ac6341-59e3-bcfe-b7f5-370100eea063/mzaf_4835051646631223146.plus.aac.p.m4a)

If I try to play this song preview using `AVPlayer` it will play successfully, but it looks like this link is not downloadable as this audio song streams.

So is there any way we can download this preview audio file so we can merge it into video.

Comment: I don't think you can, the music is copyrighted. So even if you manager it you are break the copyright.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for reply, i am following [Mindie app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mindie/id717616629?mt=8), here they provide option to choose song.

Comment: that doesn't mean that you can, maybe they have a contract with a the records copy. Just because someone else have done it, does not automatically mean you can/should.

Comment: @rckoenes ok i will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download using the following code. "**Make sure u read what @rckoenes has written**".

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL       URLWithString:@"http://a1930.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/022/Music/v4/a4/ac/63/a4ac6341-59e3-bcfe-b7f5-370100eea063/mzaf_4835051646631223146.plus.aac.p.m4a"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"recieved data");
    }
    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"empty data");
    }
    else if (error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
    {
        NSLog(@"timed out");
    }
    else if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"download error");
    }
}];
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have tried with synchronous NSURLConnection and with the code posted by you also it shows that some data is downloaded but if i write this data to file and try to play that file its not working, if i use another m4a file url its working fine, its only not working for iTunes preview files.